# Swift extensions with calculated variables with looping possible?

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to 'pretty print' an Array of Ints as hex in Swift. I have the below working as an extension of Array. But I could only get a method `arr.toHex()` to work, and not just `arr.toHex` as I wanted to do. I am wondering if it is possible at all.

Second to that, in reality I would like to do `arr as Hex` and define Hex in some way. But no idea how.

Thirdly, in my working example I needed to cast to Int to get this to work. But sometimes it will be an `Array(Uint8)` and this casting doesn't work. Should I have used an optional?

I am using the latest Swift.

```
let arr = [255, 255, 128, 64, 16]

extension Array {
    func asHex() -> String {
        var res = "0x"
        for el in self {
            res.append(String(format:"%02X", el as! Int) + " ")
        }
        return res
    }
}

print(arr.asHex())
// output: 0xFF FF 80 40 10

// would wonder whether the looping function could make into a calculated variable like this:
print(arr.asHex)
// should generate same output

// and ultimately:
print(arr as Hex)
// I have no idea how to do this
```

## Update:

Combining the answers I got very close, but I cannot get it working for `[Int]` and `[UInt8]` in one 'one liner' as I planned. I got to this to cater for both types (say `Element in [Int, UInt8]`:

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
    var asHex: String { "0x" + self.map { String(format: "%02X", $0) }.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
extension Array where Element == UInt8 {
    var asHex: String { "0x" + self.map { String(format: "%02X", $0) }.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
print( [Int(12), Int(255)].asHex )       //0x0C FF
print( [UInt8(12), UInt8(255)].asHex )   //0x0C FF
```

I now understand `Int` and `UInt8` are `BinaryInteger`s and that the `$0` in the format of the string is a `CVarArg`. For that reason I could not use `extension Array where Element: BinaryInteger` since the `$0` complained. There must be a way however. So close (and learned a lot)

Comment: Why would you need `as Hex` if you'd have a computed property `asHex`?

Comment: Or are you somehow targeting a type-cast functionality, like C++ has? Note that currently this is not possible in Swift.

Comment: `as Hex` was bad idea indeed. Was exploring. No need for it.

Answer (score 1):

To convert your function into a computed property, use this:

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
    var asHex: String {
        return self.map { String(format: "%02X", $0) }.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
```

Don't pursue the `arr as Hex` route, casting is not the right tool for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`print(arr.asHex)' won't work as you are telling it to print the method itself, not to execute the method and print the output.

If you want to lose the method signature, do it as a computed property:

```
extension Array where Element == Int{
   var asHex: String {
      var res = "0x"
      for el in self {
         res.append(String(format:"%02X", el as! Int) + " ")
      }
      return res
   }

}

let arr = [123,456,23]
print(arr.asHex)
// "0x7B 1C8 17"
```

also worth constraining the extension as above so it only works for an array of Int

Comment: You should also get rid of the `as! Int` when you constrain the extension with a where clause.  This will prevent a crash when you try to force cast the a non-integer element to Int.  I meant to delete it when I pasted your code, so it's better left in now.  Or you can use the map approach below.

Comment: got it. See my result updated with the where clause. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry too much about `as Hex`, it won't bring you too many satisfactory results in Swift. About the other two bullet points, you could simply extend all `Sequence` types that are either `Int8` or `UInt8` based with an `asHex` functionality:

```swift
func hexReduce(_ acc: String, _ el: CVarArg) -> String {
    acc + String(format: "%02X ", el)
}

extension Sequence where Self.Element == Int8 {
    var asHex: String { reduce("0x", hexReduce) }
}

extension Sequence where Self.Element == UInt8 {
    var asHex: String { reduce("0x", hexReduce) }
}

let arr1: [Int8] = [1, 2, 3]
let arr2: [UInt8] = [1, 2, 3]

print(arr1.asHex) // 0x01 02 03 
print(arr2.asHex) // 0x01 02 03
```